# How to add SQLite3 to my make file? I'm using C++ on Replit

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to create a simple C++ database project using SQLite3, but I'm getting the following error:

```
/nix/store/039g378vc3pc3dvi9dzdlrd0i4q93qwf-binutils-2.39/bin/ld: /tmp/main-ee09d1.o: in function `main':
/home/runner/DBMSProject/./main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:13: main] Error 1
```

Everything I've looked up is saying that SQLite needs to be in the make file, but I don't know how to add it in, and I haven't been able to find anything telling me how to do that. Attached is the make file

```
all: main

CXX = clang++
override CXXFLAGS += -g -Wmost -Werror

SOURCE_DIRS = . sqlite3
EXCLUDE_SRC = sqlite3/shell.c

SRCS = $(shell find . -name '.ccls-cache' -type d -prune -o -type f -name '*.cpp' -print | sed -e 's/ /\\ /g')
HEADERS = $(shell find . -name '.ccls-cache' -type d -prune -o -type f -name '*.h' -print)

main: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRCS) -o "$@"

main-debug: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -O0 $(SRCS) -o "$@"

clean:
    rm -f main main-debug
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

I tried adding the SOURCE_DIRS line and the line below it, but it didn't fix the error

Comment: Where is SQLLite3 installed?

Comment: Why do you tag [tag:C]? *C is distinct from C++ and it should not be combined with the C++ tag without a specific reason.*

Comment: What is `ccls-cache` directory?

Comment: @MartinYork I downloaded a zip file and placed them in the Replit, and used the #include function

Comment: @273K Technically SQLite3 is written in C, and I'm not sure if that would make any kind of difference or not

Comment: @MartinYork It's probably important to mention that I did not make this makefile. It was autogenerated by Replit

Comment: Your code is C++, you don't ask about the code of SQLite3.

Comment: @273K Duly noted. It looks like the tag has been removed, otherwise I would have done it myself

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
all: main

CXX       = clang++
CXXFLAGS += -Wall -Wextra -Werror

SOURCE_DIRS = . sqlite3
EXCLUDE_SRC = sqlite3/shell.c

SRCS_CPP    = $(foreach dir, $(SOURCE_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))
SRCS_C      = $(foreach dir, $(SOURCE_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
SRCS        = $(filter-out $(EXCLUDE_SRC), $(SRCS_CPP) $(SRCS_C))) 
HEADERS     = $(foreach dir, $(SOURCE_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.h))

main: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)
    @echo "SRCS: $(SRCS)"
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRCS) -O3 -o "$@"

main-debug: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -g -O0 $(SRCS) -o "$@"

clean:
    rm -f main main-debug
```

Comment: I just tried that out. It gave me the same error (Error 1), only on like 14 this time. It seems to have a problem with $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRCS) -o "$@" for some reason and I don't know why. I'm also not very experienced with makefiles in the first place

Comment: @MatthewBarlund Updated. Just realized that SQLite has C source files.

Comment: Same error, line 15 this time :(

Comment: @MatthewBarlund Added an echo command to see what you are compiling. Run that let us know what files are being included.

Comment: It returned this-

make: *** [Makefile:15: main] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target 'sqlite3/sqlite3.c)', needed by 'main'.  Stop.

Comment: @MatthewBarlund This means: `$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)` found the file `sqlite3/sqlite3.c`. But the line `main: $(SRCS) $(HEADERS)` thinks that this file is out of date so it is trying to rebuild it. But you don't have any rules defined to rebuild it. Hard to debug without being able to try it out.

Comment: @MatthewBarlund: Inite me on Replit (Loki-Astari) will be more than happy to take a look.